# Django Nested Admin validation of nested inlines from parent forms

Tags: django, django-admin, django-validation, django-3.0, django-nested-admin

What I'm trying to do is assert the `start_date` of the child form is after the `start_date` of the parent form.

For example, if I have the following models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And admin forms setup like:

```
class ChildInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = models.Child
    extra = 0


@admin.register(models.Parent)
class ParentAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildInline]
```

How would I validate the child based on the parent (or vice-versa)?

So far I've explored:

1. `Form.clean()` - but this doesn't include the child/parent instances.
2. `Formset.clean()` - but despite making formsets it appears that `django-nested-admin` ignores them and their clean methods are never used.

Has anyone found a solution for this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can still use the `model.clean()` method for form validation:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
    starts_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        parent_start = self.parent.starts_at
        child_start = self.starts_at
        if parent_start and child_start < parent_start:
            raise ValidationError(f'This group cannot start before the season starts')
```

Which will make `ValidationError` appear on the `Child` form. Using the `clean` method on the `Parent` form is also possible, and would give the errors at that level.